# How can I make a card shape around uncollapsed text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a collapsing card with a button on it that'll eventually lead to an audio file, but I also want to style it so that the card behind the button automatically changes according to the uncollapsed audio file. I know how I can do this manually, but I'd like the whole card to shape around the largest audio file.

Also: How do I move the whole card around the website? Doing style="left:??px" in the "audioplayer" div doesn't work.

```js
function search()
{
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("pgsearchbar").value;
    filter = input.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("searchitems");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++)
    {
        finder = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        letter = finder.textContent || finder.innerText;
        if (letter.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
        {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        }
        else
        {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

let counter = 0;

function increment()
{
    counter++;
    document.querySelector("#counter").innerHTML = counter;
}

function PlaySound(soundObj)
{
    var audio = document.getElementById(soundObj);
    if (audio.paused){
        audio.play();
    }
    else{
        audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
}

function reset()
{
    document.querySelector("#counter").innerHTML = 0;
    counter = 0;
}
```

```css
.pageselector
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10%;
    left:45%;
}

.banner
{
    background-image:url("sky.jpg");
    padding:60px;
    color:lightblue;
}

.banntxt
{
    font-size:50px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    font-family:"Faster One";
}

.navbar-brand
{
    font-family:"Faster One";
    font-size:25px;
}

li
{
    margin:3px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="audioplayer">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">
                            <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                Song1
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            (audio file)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                Song2
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            (audio file)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                Song3
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            (audio file)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
        <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true">
        <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true">
    </body>
</html>
```

Desired Outcome (but with the card on the far left):
[image]

Comment: You put too much code in here. Please limit to what is important for the question

Comment: @alotropico Shortened it to what's important.

Comment: Too much code to go through! Maybe  the Collapse and  Accordion examples here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/ help you.

Comment: @Jamal I shortened my code to just what's needed and I've checked bootstraps collapse component for a solution but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Please show us the desired output. Any image/video or something like that.

Comment: @Ava Edited it.

Comment: "I'd like the whole card to shape around the largest audio file" - What do you mean by this? In the image that card seems to be absolutely positioned above accordion. Did you mean like incrementing it when someone clicks on song1/song2/song3?

Comment: @Ava I realized that when I first edited my code and question, I actually fixed my problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the audio files will remain the same size due to the browser's audio control layout, so you should only have to size your card once, based on your browser's layout.

Comment: Good to see that you solved your own problem. Congrats!